# Get execution time information for large number of bash scripts

Tags: bash, profiling, sh

Given a project that consists of large number of bash scripts that are being launched from `crontab` periodically how can one track execution time of each script?

There is straightforward approach to edit each of those file by adding `date`

But what I really want is some kind of daemon that could track execution time and submit results to somewhere several times a day.

So the question is:
Is it possible to gather information about execution time of 200 bash scripts without editing each of them?

`time` module considered as fallback solution, if nothing better could be found

Comment: If your system supports `dtrace` you could set up a dtrace script to monitor the start/stop of your scripts, assuming their names are easy enough to filter through `dtrace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your systems cron implementation you may define the log-levels of the cron daemon. For ubuntus default vixie-cron setting log-level will log start and end of a job-execution which can then be analyzed.

On current LTS Ubuntu it works defining the log-level in  /etc/init/cron
appending the -L 3 option to the exec line letting it look like:

```
exec cron -L 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your cron to run your scripts under time?

`time scriptname`

And pipe output to you logs.

Comment: It is fallback option because with this solution I will need to edit cron files, looking for something more scalable

Comment: yes it is, and it still does take a lot of effort, though less effort then changing all your files.. good luck!